# Connecting Lines from One Group, Colors from Another Group

Tags: r, lattice

I have data conditioned on two variables, one major condition, one minor condition.  I want a `xyplot` (`lattice`) with points and lines (`type='b'`), in one panel so that the major condition determines the color and the minor condition is used for drawing the lines.

Here is an example that is representative of my problem (see the code below to produce the data frame).  `d` is the major condition, and `c` is the minor condition.

```
> dat
     x          y c d
1    1  0.9645269 a A
2    2  1.4892217 a A
3    3  1.4848654 a A
....
10  10  2.4802803 a A
11   1  1.5606218 b A
12   2  1.5346806 b A
....
98   8  2.0381943 j B
99   9  2.0826099 j B
100 10  2.2799917 j B
```

The way to get the connecting lines to be conditioned on `c` is to use `groups=c` in the plot.  Then the way to tell them apart is to use a formula conditioned on `d`:

```
xyplot(y~x|d, data=dat, type='b', groups=c)
```

[image]

However, I want the plots in the same panel.  Removing the formula condition on `d` produces one panel, but when `group=d` is specified, there are "retrace" lines drawn:

```
xyplot(y~x, data=dat, type='b', groups=d, auto.key=list(space='inside'))
```

[image]

What I want looks very like the above plot, only without these "retrace" lines.

It's possible to set the colors explicitly in this example, as I know that there are five lines of category 'A' followed by five of category 'B', but this won't easily work for my real problem.  In addition, `auto.key` is useless when setting the colors this way:

```
xyplot(y~x, data=dat, type='b', groups=c, col=rep(5:6, each=5))
```

[image]

The data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(1:10,
         function(x) {
           firsthalf <- x < 6
           data.frame(x=1:10, y=log(1:10 + rnorm(10, .25) + 2 * firsthalf),
                                c=letters[x],
                                d=LETTERS[2-firsthalf]
                                )
         }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default graphical parameters are obtained from the `superpose.symbol` and `superpose.line`. One solution s to set them using `par.settings` argument.

```
## I compute the color by group 
col <-by(dat,dat$c,
                FUN=function(x){
                  v <- ifelse(x$d=='A','darkgreen','orange')
                  v[1]  ## I return one parameter , since I need one color
                  }
         )

 xyplot(y~x, data=dat, type='b', groups=c,
       auto.key = list(text =levels(dat$d),points=F),
       par.settings=
         list(superpose.line   = list(col = col),                 ## color of lines
              superpose.symbol = list(col=col),                   ## colors of points
              add.text = list(col=c('darkgreen','orange'))))      ## color of text in the legend
```

[image]

Comment: Note the key.  It should have `A` and `B`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I know. I just show the key here to check if the color are ok according to the groups..I understand you don't like my solution?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I change my solution to add the Key according to the d levels.

Comment: Let me be specific, I was hoping that `lattice` had something built-in to do the color choices, but I should be able to adapt this sort of function to do the job in my real code.

Comment: I don't get all your idea. Bit if I understand you don't want to set the colors by yourself? What I did in this solution is to change the default lattice behavior when you choose `groups` are supplied.  In this case `panel.superpose` is doing the job with default setting that you can get using `trellis.par.get('superpose.line')`... It is not the same philosophy as ggplot2 where you bind any variable to any plot parameter... Maybe you can get better solution by overriding the default panel function..

Comment: I realized that this completely answers the question as posed, but the question as posed does not completely solve my problem.  I'll enter another question as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be lattice? In ggplot it is rather easy:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y,colour=d)) + geom_line(aes(group=c),size=0.8) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

This is a quick and dirty example. You can customize the colour of the lines, the legend , the  axis, the background,...

[image]

Comment: I am indeed looking for a lattice solution, but I'll accept this if I don't get one (and don't find one on my own).